# How to serialize/deserialize a map with the None values

Tags: rust, serde, toml

I need a map with the `Option` values in my configuration. However, `serde` seems to ignore any pairs with the `None` value

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use toml;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    values: HashMap<String, Option<u32>>,
}

fn main() {
    let values = [("foo", Some(5)), ("bar", None)]
        .iter()
        .map(|(name, s)| (name.to_string(), s.clone()))
        .collect();
    let config = Config { values };

    let s = toml::ser::to_string(&config).unwrap();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

produces

```
[values]
foo = 5
```

The same goes for deserializing: I simply cannot represent `bar: None` in any form,
since the TOML has no notion of `None` or `null` or alike.

Are there some tricks to do that?

Comment: Not a "trick" exactly, but you can just write a custom serializer, then attach it to `values` with [`#[serde(serialize_with = "my_serializer")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with)

Comment: What would you expect the output to be? TOML isn't designed to allow assigning null/None-type values. What are you wanting it for?

Comment: Serde is constrained by the limits of the file format you use. Toml has no notion of `None` so serde can't represent it in a Toml file. You need to either switch to a format that can represent `None` (e.g. [JSON](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66fdb0b9f4235de23c4d38969572801e)) or use a custom (de)serializer to tell serde how you want to represent `None` in Toml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest alternative I have found is to use a special sentinel value (the one you will probably use in `Option::unwrap_or`), which appears in the TOML file as the real value (e.g. `0`), and converts from `Option::None` on serialization. But on deserialization, the sentinel value converts to `Option::None` and leaves us with the real `Option` type.

Serde has a special `#[serde(with = module)]` attribute to customize the ser/de field behavior, which you can use here. The full working example is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81453e3e0b82ac8bf67f7d4d32fba584).